# Is it possible to have XML Code Comments pass through from an Interface to the Implementing class while using `var` syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, comments

Imagine the following code

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets bar
    /// </summary>
    string Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo // fixed, as a miss from my simplified example for SO
{
    public string Bar() { return "Bar"; }
}
```

Visual Studio correctly shows the code comments in the intellisense popup when you code like this:

```
IFoo instance = new Foo(); // shows what is in IFoo
```

but if you use the `var` syntax it does not show the code comments from the interface

```
var instance = new Foo(); // only shows what is in class Foo
```

In an attempt to remediate this, I've tried throwing a `<see>` tag into the summary on class Foo which points to interface IFoo, however this doesn't work.

Is there a tag/way to allow the interface comments to pass through in all use cases?

For what its worth, I did read/review [this question on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1875440/86860), providing two different comments isn't realistic for every method in every case (often they're one and the same, used only for injection and testing) so providing different flavor comments on both wont work, at least not for all cases.

Comment: If you are using Resharper than inheritdoc tag should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "inheritdoc" element in the XML documentaion.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// gets Bar
    /// </summary>
    string Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    /// <inheritdoc />       
    public string Bar() { return "Bar"; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your code doesn't implement the interface... but that's not the cause. 
How about including the summary block in the implementation as well as in the interface?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// gets Bar
    /// </summary>
    string Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// gets Bar
    /// </summary>        
    public string Bar() { return "Bar"; }
}
```

Comment: This is quite redundant and prone to getting out of sync. In many cases, the *should* be the same, but I don't want to maintain two separate copies manually. Thus my question, is there a way to do this without manually keeping two copies in sync?